# Ubuntu 13.04 - some empathy plugins don't work

Tags: empathy, 13.04

I observed on newly installed Ubuntu 13.04 that only Google plugin used in Empathy.
Meanwhile I have some additional plugins:

- ICQ. Contacts not shown in Empathy. Detail card in Network Accounts is empty so I draw a conclusion that problem with ICQ deeper.
- Facebook. Contacts not shown in Empathy. Detail card in Network Accounts looks well.

What's up with these plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem. There is a problem with the implementation of these plugins. The only way I managed to solve it was to uninstall Empathy and install Pidgin instead.

Comment: I agree with Rafael that this is a bug. Since a few people seem to have the problem and I couldn't find a bug report on launchpad, I [created one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/1177391).

Answer (score -1):

Try `sudo apt-get install account-plugin-icq`.

This can resolve your trouble. But some problems still persists.